# What materials from nature can you use to build a pair of skis on a mountain?

Tags: survival, skiing, mountains

I'm working on a survival story and want to make it authentic. If you were stranded on a mountain trying to get down as fast as possible, what would you do?

EDIT:
What if this was after a plane crash on a desolate snowy mountain? Would it be possible to fashion some kind of combination from debris and nature to propel down the mountain?

Comment: Do you have any equipment with you?  If you do, I'd add to the answer of  @helm (with which I agree): (1) sit on your foam sleeping pad; and (2) use a hiking stick to help slow you down.

Comment: Can you add more details about the mountain, the place where your character is stranded, tools at hand and the path to eventual safety?
Building a pair of skis might be somewhat plausible for someone stuck in a cabin and some time to spend. Outside, above the treeline however... no.

Comment: This question should be on [World building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: @GabrielC. You are welcome to bring it up on meta, but the consensus the last time  this was brought up is that these types of questions are on topic

Comment: your story sounds similar to the game = The Long Dark

Answer (score 5):

From your heading I gather the mountain in your story is covered in snow.

If the slope allows it, then I'd skid down on my behind. Grab something like a suitably formed stone to be able to perform a [self-arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-arrest).
Any kind of skis you could expect to build up there would perform far worse.

Answer (score 3):

The technique @helm recommends is (at least in this neck of the woods) called a "[Glissade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glissade_(climbing))". It is essentially "*a method of descending a steep snow-covered slope via a controlled slide on one's feet or buttocks*". I have heard of people using other items to assist in a glissade by using them as a sort of sled, a backpack or as in Ed Abbey's Desert Solitaire; a large flat rock.

If I were you I would spend some time googling this term as it is a more realistic way to quickly improvise ones way off a mountain, rather than taking the time to attempt to fashion proper skis.

Now, depending on the type of story you're writing, you could have your character just strap a couple felled logs to their feet at let fly! [AKA Paul Bunyan](https://www.skimag.com/ski-resort-life/how-paul-bunyan-invented-skiing).